# How to get All messages in FOSMessageBundle of Symfony2 Where participant is xyz?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, message-bundle

I am trying to fetch all messages of FOSMessageBundle in symfony2 where participant is xyz , This is giving me only inbox messages .

```
public function getMessagesAction() {
    $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
    $entity = $this->getProvider()->getInboxThreads();
}
```

Is there any way to get All messages for a particular participant .

I am new for Symfony don't have more knowledge about it.

Comment: You can also call getSentThreads()

Comment: How to call both at a time n how to store both the results in same $entity ?  pls tell me if u know

Comment: $product = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:Product')
        ->find($id);